# Tools to optimize SQL Server data types?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I tried Googling a bit, but I can’t seem to find anything to help me here: Are there any tools or scripts that will “analyse” all the tables in a database, and give recommendations for optimizing the data types based on the values they currently hold?

For example:

- int column that holds no values above 255 would be better as a tinyint.
- int or char columns with only “1” and “0” should be bit.
- guids stored as varchar, should be uniqueidentifier.
- numeric values stored as varchar.
- or you could even get really clever and detect IP addresses stored as varchar and suggest changing it to a bigint.

Comment: Yes - that tool is called "DBA" :-)

Comment: Hehe, true: But I think most DBAs (or some at least) would like to get a quick overview easily so they have some ammunition for complaining about devs messing up their databases... :) I wouldn't be surprised if a smart DBA somewhere already has a script to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any off hand, but I feel it should be design/modeling task, or should be something that should be gone through by a human... any tool wouldn't know why somebody chose int vs tinyint - because maybe the application business logic allows values larger than 255, but the values thus far are all less than 255.

Comment: I totally agree, all the recommendations should of course be evaluated by a developer who knows the businesslogic. But it would be really nice with a tool that could go over hundreds of tables automatically and point to areas of interest. Maybe the original developer didn't care much of storage issues, but it eventually has become a problem, and a new guy is assigned to clean it up: Where to start?? :)

Comment: Yeah, I hear ya. I googled, too, couldn't find anything. I would say just attack the tables one by one :(